# Cannot install AutoIT library for Robot Framework

Tags: autoit, robotframework

I'm going to install AutoIT library for Robot framework to do automation task for Win Application, during on this, I've encountered a problem as below:

---

```
My OS : Win Vista 32-bits

1. Install Python 2.7.6 using Windows installer 
2. Install Robot Framework using 'pip' command line
3. Run 'python setup.py install' from C:/temp/AutoItLibrary-1.1 (unzipped) by Administration permission.
```

---

The command line show error:

```
Don't think we need to unregister the old one...
%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll
The system cannot find the path specified.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 70, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C:\Python27\Lib\site-p
ackages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

---

So, Does the version Autoit_1.1. match with Win Vista or not ? please help me figure out the issue.

Comment: Does the file **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll** exist on your system?

Comment: Interesting, since it seems as if the installer can't find the file. See line 56/57 of [https://github.com/zheli/robotframework-autoitlibrary-forked/blob/master/setup.py](https://github.com/zheli/robotframework-autoitlibrary-forked/blob/master/setup.py). Try to open a shell as administrator and run the setup from there.

Comment: I run as Administrator but the result hasn't changed. Would you liek to recommend other solutions ?

Comment: This is a guide to do the set up on Window 7 but it might also help you: http://www.testingnotes.eu/howto-install-robot-framework-windows-7-64/

Comment: It cannot solve my issue

Comment: Then I don't have any idea, sorry.

Comment: I'll fix this problem by installing AutoIT on local computer (log to computer by local account) not member of domain(log with domain). And it's solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll fix this problem by installing AutoIT on local computer (log to computer by local account) not member of domain(log with domain). And it's solved.

Comment: One more way, you can un-plug the network cable of your machine in case your computer is joined Netowrk domain

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was solved setting the missing environment variable `HOMEDRIVE` **and** run `python setup.py install` as administrator. My Python is installed in `C:\Python27` so I need to set `HOMEDRIVE` to `C:`

Answer (score 1):

Login as an Administrator to console and then install (case from win 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing wheel before installing robotframework-autoitlibrary.
It worked like a charm.

```
pip install wheel
```

then

```
pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by the following steps:

1> go to 
http://www.testingnotes.eu/howto-install-robot-framework-windows-7-8-64/

find the paragraph as below:

> 8. Download AutoIT library (64bits) from here:
>
> AutoItLibrary-1.1_x64
>
> 8.1. Unzip “AutoItLibrary-1.1_x64” folder. (i.e. in this example I will unzip to  “C:\”)
>
> 8.2. Open command shell as Administrator. Click on “Start”, type “cmd”, right click > “Run as Administrator“).
>
> 8.3. Go to AutoIT folder (i.e. in this example I had to type: “cd C:\AutoItLibrary-1.1_x64”
>
> 8.4. Run configuration script: type “setup.py install” and ENTER.

the key point  is

> 8.2. Open command shell as Administrator. Click on “Start”, type “cmd”, right click > “Run as Administrator“).

2> just do it: Click on “Start”, type “cmd”, right click > “Run as Administrator“.

I am from China, before answer the question when I get the solution, I need to over the wall. It is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything under Python/AutoItLibrary folder:
..\Python36\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary

and rerun python setup.py install

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

run pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary as an admin.